# Relation between file size and file content

Tags: file, byte

I created a file in the text editor with 6 letters and then checked the file size. It shows 7 bytes instead of 6 bytes. why?

Comment: Perhaps some whitespace or e line break somewhere? I just set up a simple file saying "123456" (with no whitespace or line breaks) in an editor on a Windows machine, and, as expected, the file size was 6 bytes.

Comment: No. There is no whitespace or line break. It shows 7 bits for '123456' also.

Comment: Seems to differ by operating system. Some might put an end-of-file marker that takes up a byte.